# get absolute path for an image to send in email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, filepath

I have a view (with one or more images) that I also want to use as the body of an email message. The Model serving the view uses `Url.Content()` to retrieve the absolute image path. This approach works fine for web pages, but when I render the exact same view as the body of the email, then the image can not be found which is suggested by the incomplete path from the rendered html.

```
 <img src="/Media/fe882a1d-3b77-4264-ab91-cade985ecbed.JPG"/>
```

I know that this problem can be fixed if I could access the full url such as with `Url.Action` with the

```
Request.Url.Scheme
```

overload for protocol. Is there a way to determine the fully qualified URL from `Url.Content`?

Comment: Is the name of image determined?

Comment: why dont u try Server.MapPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writting your own url extension method and resolve with the help of `Uri.GetLeftPart & UriPartial.Authority`

```
public static class UrlExtensions
{
  public static string AbsoluteContent(this UrlHelper urlHelper
                                     , string contentPath)
  {
   Uri requestUrl = urlHelper.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;

   string absolutePath = string.Format("{0}{1}",
                          requestUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority),
                          urlHelper.Content(contentPath));
   return absolutePath;

  }

}
```

Then use `Url.AbsoluteContent("~/media/image.jpeg")` in your pages. It will render `http://domain/media/image.jpeg`