# Deploying MVC Program with separate stylesheets

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to deploy an ASP.NET MVC project. The resulting output shows that the stylesheets have not been picked up.

This is my code referencing the stylesheets:

```html
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    <link href= "<%= Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href= "<%= Url.Content("~/Content/style_custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href= "<%= Url.Content("~/Content/styleIFrame_custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</asp:Content>
```

In Publish/Package settings, I can select Items to deploy. I have choice of:

- Only files needed to run this application.
- All files in this project.
- All files in this project folder.

Not sure which one to pick, but I have tried all 3. The wrong option leads to an enormous deployment package.

On the deployment machine, my source code resolves to this:

```html
<link href= "/KeyStone/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href= "/KeyStone/Content/style_custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href= "/KeyStone/Content/styleIFrame_custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Maybe my only option is to put the styles in the page itself and scrap the stylesheets. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/22711498/1559213 may be helpful

Comment: I thought the default was "All files in the project" (and usually works well for everything I need)... If you select that and pry open the deployment package, they're not there?